# Ruby on Rails: Submitting to table two different ways

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, database, controller

I have an app where the user can submit a project. For each field they have a choice of either putting in new data into the database, or selecting old data from past projects to fill that field.

I am having trouble getting this to work for this piece of code in my New view:

```
<%= form_for(@technol) do |tech| %>   

<%= fields_for(@project_technol) do |ab| %>

<%=  text_field_tag :tech, nil, :maxlength => 30 %>
OR<br />

<%= ab.label "All Tech"%> </br>
<%= collection_select( :technols, :id, Technol.all, :id, :tech, {}, {:multiple => true } ) %>
</div>
<% end %>

<% end %>
```

At the moment the user can select many technologies from the collection_select, and they get saved with the project, but I am trying to give them the option to put there own technologies in through a text box.

My controller actions:

**NEW**

```
def new
   @project = Project.new
   @technol = Technol.new(params[:tech])

   @all_technols = Technol.all
   tech_ids = params[:technols][:id].reject(&:blank?) unless params[:technols].nil?


   @project_technol = @project.projecttechnols.build

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # new.html.erb
      format.json { render json: @project }
    end
  end
```

**CREATE**

```
def create

    @project = Project.new(params[:project])


params[:technols][:id].each do |tech|

if !tech.empty?

@project.projecttechnols.build(:technol_id => tech) 

end

end

    respond_to do |format|
      if @project.save
        format.html { redirect_to @project, notice: 'Project was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render json: @project, status: :created, location: @project }
      else
        format.html { render action: "new" }
        format.json { render json: @project.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
```

So to sum up, I want the user to have the option to enter new tech into the database, AND select existing tech from the dropdown, then all get saved with the project, and the new tech entered get saved in the technol table.

Any ideas? I am a rails noob so please remember this when trying to answer. Any help will be much appreciated. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

How about using token fields instead of a drop down and text field?

Check this revised RailsCast:
http://railscasts.com/episodes/258-token-fields-revised

Here's the original screen cast that's free if you don't have a RailsCast subscription:
http://railscasts.com/episodes/258-token-fields

Comment: I have followed this video exactly, and the autocomplete doesn't seem to load.

Answer (score 0):

I will suggest you to use a autocomplete which accepts multiple values. which will improve your view plus the coding will be easy